# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected error in oracle

Tags: oracle, ora-00923

I have following Store procedure in Oracle 11g. I am passing the table name as parameter through ASP.net using c#. But while running the application i am getting the error "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected error in oracle".

```
PROCEDURE "ARCHIVE_FILTERDATA" ( ITYPE IN VARCHAR2, itableName IN VARCHAR2, cur_archive OUT sys_refcursor ) AS 

stmt clob; 

endstmt clob; 

BEGIN

IF ITYPE='Week' 
THEN stmt := 'DELETE FROM '|| itableName ||' WHERE CREATEDATE < (SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL , - 1, WEEK))'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt; 

END IF;

END;
```

So anybody have a solution please let me know ASAP. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your inner SELECT must have FROM

Comment: Plus there is neither a `date_add()` nor a `curdate()`  function in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

You have three errors in your `DELETE` statement:

1. there is no `date_add()` function in Oracle ([See the manual for a list of available functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions.htm#SQLRF006))
2. there is no `curdate()` function in Oracle ([See the manual for a list of available functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions.htm#SQLRF006))
3. The sub-query is totally unnecessary. Plus: a `select` requires a `from` clause.

Putting it all together, your delete should look like this:

```
stmt := 'DELETE FROM '|| itableName ||' WHERE CREATEDATE < sysdate - interval ''1'' week';
```

(Note the duplicated single quotes inside the string literal).

Be aware that Oracle's `DATE` datatype *always* contains a time part. So `sysdate - interval '1' week` will return the date one week ago a the "current time". If you mean to include the complete day last week, you need to "remove" the time part by using trunc: `trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' week`.

Answer (score -1):

You inner query will look alike:-

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL , - 1, WEEK) FROM DUAL;
```

So plz correct your query.

Comment: There is neither a `date_add` nor a `curdate()` function in Oracle.